# Remove traffic from unwanted domains from GA4

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

How can I exclude traffic coming from particular domain in GA4 property?
There are some websites that we no longer use and don't have access to its codebase, and those websites have our GTM script enabled in it due to which we are still receiving the traffic from it. I did add the regex for Page Views in GTM tag but we are still getting sessions from those domains. We are still receiving data from unwanted domains.
And FYI, we are using same GTM container for multiple GA4 properties.

I have tried to exclude it using IP addresses via internal traffic option. I tried referral exclusion as well. Nothing worked. It just removed developer data only.

Is there another way to exclude particular domain in GA4, just like we used to have in UA?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you didn't realize it, GA4 is a considerable downgrade functionality-wise with a few buggy upgrades of the UI.

Your solution, however, is in GTM. Since these sites still use your GTM, you can just add a blocking condition in GTM to prevent it from tracking anything on those sites. Or anything on any sites that aren't yours.

You could also use your GTM container to deploy something onto their sites. Something like "Please remove the GTM container" to their footer. But it's up to you. I would first try to reach out to them and notify them that they're loading a container they have no control over.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I did add the blocking condition on configuration tags for the respective GA4 properties on GTM. The thing is we have more than 500 tags on our GTM container. Do you think that UA tags might be interfering with GA4 data?

Comment: UA tags can interfere with GA4 data if the UA property is linked to the GA4 one. There was an easy migration option where you just linked UA to GA4 and didn't need to change the tracking. A very limited option. Few people used it.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps you can follow to exclude the traffic from unwanted domains/subdomains:

1. Open your GA4 and select the right property
2. Go to admin
3. Open open **Data streams** and open detail of the data stream
4. On Details page, scroll down and click on **Configure tag settings**
5. Scroll down and click on **Show more**
6. Click on **List Unwanted referrals**
7. Click on **Add condition** button
8. Click on **Referral domain contains** from the drop down of Match type
9. Enter the url of the domain or subdomain you want to exclude in referral
10. Click on **Save**

and you are **done**!

For more details you can follow watch this Youtube video:
https://youtu.be/BA6S-T5hHE8?si=_fhcz6xcQuhfbKmX